# How to fix 303 See Other error in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have deployed the same code on two different servers. Everything is working perfectly on both servers, except for one URL.

When I try to access this URL, it gives me this status code:

```
Status Code: 303 See Other
```

Comment: There was an issue because of redirect, and it's working fine now.

Comment: How do you fix it?

Comment: Did you hosted in Godaddy?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with Sessions in codeigniter  and has been re written in CodeIgniter 3, kindly visit below link to use the proper configuration.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html

Comment: There was an issue because of redirect, and it's working fine now. :)